# How to make all my divs line up together nicely

Tags: javascript, html

I've been playing around with my code, I have the Calendar set up to do what i want, now I am just trying to get the `<p>` and iframe lined up beside each other nicely, i have this code so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2HK9/) and here is an example of what the separation f the arrows and iframe looks like [now](http://hardknocks365.com)

what i want to achieve:

> 200px----[  arrowLEFT ]---30px---[  Iframe  ]---30px---[  arrowRIGHT 
>   ]

HTML:

```
<div id="miniFeed">


<p id="toggle">
<span> <a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"
onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('LeftArrow','','WEBgraphics/arrowLeftROLL.png',1)">
<img src="WEBgraphics/arrowLeft.png" width="40" height="400" id="LeftArrow"></a></span>
<span> </span>
</p>



<div id="calender">


<div id="left"> <iframe src="calenderAPRIL.html" width="350px" height="400px"></iframe>   
</div>

<div id="right"> <iframe src="calenderMAY.html" width="350px" height="400px"></iframe>   
</div>


</div>

<p id="toggle">

<span> </span>

<span> <a href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"  
onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('RightArrow','','WEBgraphics/arrowrightROLL.png',1)">
<img src="WEBgraphics/arrowright.png" width="40" height="400" id="RightArrow"></a></span>   
</p>



</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
window.onload=function() {
$('#toggle > span').click(function() {
var ix = $(this).index();

$('#left').toggle( ix === 0 );
$('#right').toggle( ix === 1 );
});
};
```

CSS:

```
#miniFeed {
}
#right { display:none; }
#LeftArrow {
z-index: 100;
width: auto;
float: left;
margin-left: 200px;
display: block;
}
#calender {
float: left;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: "MM_swapImage" really? The 1990's called. They want their scripts back.

Comment: and they just called again, they wanted their lame joke back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

html:

```
<div id="miniFeed">
<div class="arrow leftArrow">        
</div>
<div class="calendars">
     <div class="carousel">
        <div class="calendar-1">                        
        </div>
        <div class="calendar-2">            
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow rightArrow">        
</div>
```

css:

```
#miniFeed {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;    
}

#miniFeed > div {
    float: left;    
     height: 100%;
}

.arrow {    

    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.calendars {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden; /*the magic*/
}

.carousel {
    width: 400px; /* the size is number of calendars * the width per calendar */
    height: 100%;    
}

.carousel > div {    
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.calendar-1 {
  background: red;   
}

.calendar-2 {
  background: green;   
}
```

js:

```
$('.leftArrow').click(function() {
    //we move the carousel negative
    //the value 200 is the width of a calendar
    $('.carousel').animate({marginLeft: -200}, 300);
});

$('.rightArrow').click(function() {
    //we move the carousel negative
    $('.carousel').animate({marginLeft: 0}, 300);
});
```

We create a wrapper with overflow hidden, so inside it we have our collections of calendars.

Result:
http://jsfiddle.net/renanvalentin/kzTRz/

Comment: the html part of my code was really complicated to get working so i dont really want to mess around with the <p toogle> and <div> classes

Comment: set your div calender with a fixed width and height and overflow hidden, its works.